# Error while using AVAudioSession in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I used these codes

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (
                                 kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
                                 audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,
                                 self
                                 );
NSError *activationError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
}
```

and

```
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID, UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue ) {
    // ensure that this callback was invoked for a route change
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;


    {
        // Determines the reason for the route change, to ensure that it is not
        //      because of a category change.
        CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = (CFDictionaryRef)inPropertyValue;

        CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue (routeChangeDictionary, CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason) );
        SInt32 routeChangeReason;
        CFNumberGetValue (routeChangeReasonRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &routeChangeReason);

        if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {

            //Handle Headset Unplugged
        } else if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_NewDeviceAvailable) {
            //Handle Headset plugged in
        }

    }
}
```

to detect if audio jack is plugged in or out in my project but I end up with this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So what is the issue in it? I'm a beginner in ios any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have miss to add `AudioToolBox.Frameworks` to project file. Double check with your project file setting..

**Update** 
Actually missed AVFoundation.Frameworks to add in the build phase of project.

**Update 2**
The trailing `s` has been removed. Now it is `AudioToolBox.Framework` and `AVFoundation.Framework`

Comment: Did you import this one `import<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` and did you add `AVFoundation.Frameworks`?

Comment: Yes I imported <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

Comment: Yes AVFoundation.Frameworks not added in build phase now I added manually it works thanks