# AudioSessionGetProperty Undefined Symbols i386

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I am trying to set my AVAudioSession category based on whether or not audio is already playing, and after reading the Apple Dev Docs for AVAudioSession, I came up with this code, taken straight from their solution for what I was trying to accomplish:

```
UInt32 otherAudioIsPlaying;                                   // 1
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof (otherAudioIsPlaying);

AudioSessionGetProperty (                                     // 2
                         kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying,
                         &propertySize,
                         &otherAudioIsPlaying
                         );

if (otherAudioIsPlaying) {                                    // 3
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
     setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
     error: nil];
} else {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
     setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient
     error: nil];
}
```

Everything compiles correctly, but when I try to build and run the app, I get a Mach-O Linker error corresponding to `AudioSessionGetProperty`.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_AudioSessionGetProperty", referenced from:
+[AppDelegate setAudioSession] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**I imported** the `AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h` file into my AppDelegate (where the code is being executed). **I also imported** the AVFoundation framework into the project binary itself. Am I missing another framework that is required for this method? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You probably don't have the framework imported, add it from the 
"Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries" menu if it's not there (AVFoundation.framework)

Comment: AVFoundation.framework is listed under "Link Binary with Libraries".

Comment: hmmm that's weird, does importing AVAudioSession.h fix it ?

Comment: Nope. Still get the error.

Comment: Can you give the link to the example you're following ?

Comment: Check the subsection titled "Checking if Other Audio is Playing During App Launch". That's where I got it from. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW6

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31830/discussion-between-mostafa-torbjorn-berg-and-david)

Comment: After doing some searching on armv7 Audio Sessions, I came up with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162145/error-while-using-avaudiosession-in-ios Apparently I also needed the AudioToolbox framework. Never heard of it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: perfect, I was just telling you to try including it (in chat), glad you found it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who may be having this problem:

In order to get the audiosession property in this manner, it requires the `AudioToolbox` framework. Add that library to your project and import it and the linker error will go away.